# Long Polling - Best way to timing out a request after certain seconds

Tags: php, nginx, long-polling

Taking a long polling request, if the server does not respond after a certain period an unpleasant error is returned (405 with nginx). How to expire the request with PHP after certain seconds? How many seconds you recommend? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: what is the php doing exactly, is it looping/sleeping waiting for something ?

Comment: Yes, it is a looping waiting for something.

Comment: can you share that part of the code, then I'll answer your question

Comment: The code is very simple, it is a while(1) (infinite loop) and there is a sql statement and at the end of while a random sleep (1 or 3 sec).

Comment: is your javascript designed to reconnect if the connection is terminated ?, if not how exactly is it done

Comment: Yes of course, my javascript designed to reconnect if the connection is terminated, only that I would break the connection with php, do not want to wait for the server returns error 405. And then I want to know how many seconds are recommended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then here's how i would do it , I already built a similar script for one of my spare time projects, instead of doing a full infinite loop, i would do a loop with a limited number of loops, and a sleep in the middle to save the extensive cpu usage, might not exactly how your code is designed but it's good, and it stops gracefully with a normal 200 code, of course you can change the loop counter and the sleep value to suit your code.

```
<?php
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
    $i = 60;
    while($i--){
        echo "data: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n\n";
        echo "\n\n";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
```

Then leave it for the javascript to reconnect and start a new loop.

**PS:** Do you actually get your data to stream? or does the stream stay blank till the connection is terminated?

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I like your solution, I do, however, a question. In this way the cycle is 60 attempts, since there is the sleep of 1 second is likely to suprerare the limit of 60 seconds if there are no results, and then of being returned error 405, is not it?

Comment: you can extend the normal limit of nginx, let me look for the config

Comment: try something like `fastcgi_read_timeout 2m;` (2 mins timeout) in a location block that would include the long polling, like `location /longpoll` for example